# button only disabled on first question but doesn't reset to disabled on the next question

Tags: javascript, html

So I created a function that checks if one of the 4 boxes is checked before continuing on to the next question. currently, it applies to the first question but doesn't reset for the next question resulting in being able to loop through the quiz without being able to not answer. I have tried calling back to the function through an event listener for the button and the function for nextQuestion but it still doesn't work. is there any other method I could try?

```
let answerChecked = false

answerSelector.forEach(function (item) {
item.addEventListener("click", function(){
answerChecked = true;
selectedAnswer();
 })
});

function selectedAnswer(){
if (answerChecked) {
submitBtn.disabled = false;
} else {
submitBtn.disabled = true
}
}
```

edit figure it out just add answerChecked = false to eventlisterner  onclick

Comment: how can I revert it to false.

Comment: can you provide the complete code.

Comment: I figure it out.

Comment: Congratulations @Huey O'Brien.